# Where can I find the Application Data folder in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I'm using Windows 7 and want to back up some files and it read somewhere that they should be in a folder called "Application Data", but I have no idea where to find this folder!

I tried looking for C:\Users\Ivo\Application Data, but there's nothing there.

So where can I find this folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To show the AppData folder:

- Launch Windows Explorer and choose Organize->Folder and search options:

[image]

- Select Show hidden files, folders, and drives.
- Uncheck Hide protected operating system files.

[image: failed URL 2]

- Click OK.

In Windows Explorer Navigate to the current user's AppData folder under:

drive:\Users\Username\AppData

[image: failed URL 3:]

Answer (score 2):

It's called AppData in 7 and it's hidden. So it would be C:\Users\Ivo\AppData

Comment: be sure and enable `hidden files and folders` in Folder Options...

Answer (score 2):

Head over to `Control Panel` -> `Folder Options`. Click on `View` tab & enable radiobox `Show Hidden Files & Folders`. Also, clear checkbox `Hide Protected Operating System files`

[image]

Then head over to `C:\Users\Ivo\AppData`. You'll find Roaming & Local folders - backup both.

(If I'm mistaken in folder names, do forgive, I'm away from my Win 7 laptop & relying on my memory)

Answer (score 1):

Start, type

```
%appdata%
```

Hit enter.

Solution applies to most versions of Windows.

Comment: This takes you to `Roaming` folder in Win 7

Comment: ...which is a subfolder of Appdata